Connecting to SharePoint Online is not working as I expected
I'm trying to connect to my development SharePoint Online instance. The requirement will ultimately be to retrieve the document library list of folders, but for now I am having issues just getting logged in. I've tried a number of different Python packages and methods. Credentials, tokens, and certificates. Certificates era the most recent method.
I keep getting stuck on what seems like relatively simple things.  This evening it is an undeclared variable for 'access_token' when I have code that declares the variable a couple of lines earlier.
Here is my code snippet:
    *scopes_sharepoint_online = ["https://sitexyz.sharepoint.com/"]

    results = msal_app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes_sharepoint_online)

    if "access_token" in results:
      access_token = results.get("access_token")

    headers = {
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",  **It keeps balking here**
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    sharepoint_base_url = "https://sitexyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sync"

    sharepoint_url = f"{sharepoint_base_url}/_api/web/sitegroups"

    response = requests.get(url=sharepoint_url, headers=headers)

    print(response.status_code)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)) *

Any ideas would be much appreciated.
I've tried declaring the variable before the block, and that was ignored.

I think the issue you're facing seems to be related to the scope of the access_token variable. It looks like the code is trying to use access_token in the headers dictionary, but it may not be declared if the results dictionary doesn't contain access_token. This will result in a NameError.
